# Extrair data de texto após palavra - Regex Python

Tags: python, regex

Preciso extrair a data de um texto que contém várias datas, mas tenho que extrair somente a data após determinada palavra aparecer.

Exemplo:

```py
string = 'Termo de mídias sociais OK 26/07/2018. Usuário bloqueado conforme solicitado via e-mail 05/08/2021 - FS.'
palavra_chave = 'bloqueado|desativado'
```

> Retorno esperado = '05/08/2021'

Preciso extrair sempre e somente a data que aparece após a palavra *bloqueado* ou *desativado* podendo ter várias palavras entre a palavra chave e a data, nesse caso retornaria a data 05/08/2021.

O máximo que consegui chegar foi nisso `(?<=bloqueado|desativado)(.*?)(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})` que isola toda a cadeia de texto após a palavra chave e a data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não precisa do *lookbehind* (o trecho que começa com `(?<=`).

E o trecho que pega a data está entre parênteses, o que cria um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). Então basta capturar o grupo:

```py
import re

string = 'Termo de mídias sociais OK 26/07/2018. Usuário bloqueado conforme solicitado via e-mail 05/08/2021 - FS.'
r = re.compile(r'(?:bloqueado|desativado).*?(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})')

match = r.search(string)
if match:
    print(match.group(1)) # 05/08/2021
```

Repare também que no início coloquei `(?:`, que cria um grupo de não-captura. Se eu não colocasse, este trecho seria o grupo 1 e a data ficaria no grupo 2. Mas eu preferi não criar grupos à toa.

---

E a partir do Python 3.8 você pode usar uma [*assignment expression*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#assignment-expressions):

```
if match := r.search(string):
    print(match.group(1))
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado!